# Invoke a thread from callback and pass structure by value

Tags: c, callback, pthreads

I need to create a thread from a callback function in C.

My aim is to do processing in thread so that callback function doesn't have to wait.

Example:

```
static void cbFunc() {

    //do some processing
    //invoke a thread and pass structure to thread by value
    //return from callback function

}
```

Can someone please help me to do this efficiently?

Comment: You would typically use a queue. The callback function pushes the pending work object on the queue, and a background thread - started previously for this purpose - will look for work in this queue and process it when found.

Comment: You can't. malloc it and pass the pointer from malloc.

Comment: Can you share me the example for pushing pending work to queue. Can thread pool be used? Also I do not want to block callback function, hence need to push data to queue needed as well.

Comment: Sure, using a thread pool should work well for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks. How can I pass structure data to a thread pool which is created in callback function? Data should be accessible in thread pool even if callback function returns.

Comment: Sounds like you need a custom class type. It's impossible for me to make more specific recommendations with no knowledge of the actual application.

Comment: The callback function is extracting captured frame from camera and need to pass this to thread for further processing. But I do not want to block callback function to wait for processing to complete. So I need to pass captured frame to thread and return from callback function. Definitely the scope of frame will be lost as soon as function scope ends. But thread can continue processing is what I need.

Comment: Looks like I can use your idea of queue for data as well. Put data to queue and pop latest data from queue in thread pool worker function. Let me know if there are any other better approaches as well.